# Certain 1970 dates don't get converted correctly from UTC to local time

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Certain dates in 1970 (and the previous couple of years) don't convert correctly from UTC to local time, where the time zone is GMT.

For example:

```
var foo = new DateTime(1970, 11, 19, 23, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

var zone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");
var zoneDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(foo, zone);
Console.WriteLine(foo);
Console.WriteLine(zoneDateTime);
```

outputs

```
11/19/1970 11:00:00 PM
11/19/1970 11:00:00 PM
```

However, in 1970, GMT was always UTC + 1:

[image]

(Source: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/uk/london)

Indeed, if I run the same code for the previous month that year, I get this:

```
10/19/1970 11:00:00 PM
10/20/1970 12:00:00 AM
```

(Which I believe is correct.)

Is this a bug in .NET?

The reason that this is an issue for us is that browser date objects appear to handle this correctly (in UK timezone), e.g. demonstrated via momentjs:

```
moment("1970-11-19T23:00:00Z").local().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')

> "1970-11-20 00:00:00"
```

[Update: Chrome "works", IE does the same thing as .NET]

So setting a date in the UI (say date of birth - ok, we shouldn't be using a time portion for that), posting it to .NET as a UTC date, then converting back to local time, is causing problems.

Comment: UTC did not exist in 1970.  If you really care about the oddest quirks in the dark corners of the calendar, suggest perhaps you look into [NodaTime](https://nodatime.org/)

Comment: @J... GMT did though, and that's the same.

Comment: @phuzi UTC was in development for several decades prior, but the transition to the UTC standard did not happen until Jan 1st, 1972.

Comment: No, this is not a bug in .NET (although it depends on your point of view, I suppose). .NET can only use the time zone info as part of the OS, and Windows doesn't record time zone information that far back. Per earlier comments, you need something like NodaTime, or other sources of complete time zone histories.

Comment: @phuzi That said, yes, the UK did run a BST experiment from 1969-1971.  The .NET time system isn't "buggy", per se, it's just not complete.  NodaTime is what you want if you want to capture these types of edge-case oddities in the history of time.

Comment: +1 for NodaTime. If your application deals with dates or date math, I would highly recommend using it over `DateTime`.

Comment: Be careful using NodaTime, the timezone database will not get updated automatically, unlike Windows. There is some [info on the NodaTime site](https://nodatime.org/2.4.x/userguide/tzdb) on how to keep it up to date though.

Comment: Note the "update" in my question on browser handling - IE appears to handle 1970 dates like .NET, Chrome handles them like NodaTime.  Therefore, using NodaTime to convert UTC dates posted by IE could still cause issues.  I get the feeling we should just be posting the date as a string for date of birth (i.e. no date/time conversion required).

Comment: In theory there might also be JS libraries that incorporate their own TZ database info and do not rely on the browser for this (leading to the discrepancies with IE, which apparently in turn relies on the OS for the info, as IE would of course be wont to do while Chrome would not be), although I don't know if there are. Either find and use one of those for client-side conversion or, indeed, don't convert client-side (but in the latter case, take care that correct TZ info is included when posting to the server -- the user's local TZ might not be, if the time is about some event elsewhere).